# ItemsSource items are being duplicated

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a custom `Ribbon` control which has an `ItemsSource` dependency property. This property is a type of `IList<RibbonItem>`. I'm setting its `ItemsSource` in XAML like this:

```
<customcontrols:Ribbon.ItemsSource>
    <customcontrols:RibbonItem x:Name="InsertRibbonItem"
                               Key="insert-item"
                               TabHeader="Insert">
        <customcontrols:RibbonItem.ItemsSource>
            <customcontrols:RibbonSection SectionHeader="Layout"
                                          SeparatorColor="#ccc" />
        </customcontrols:Ribbon.ItemsSource>
    </customcontrols:RibbonItem>
    <customcontrols:RibbonItem x:Name="DesignRibbonItem"
                               Key="design-item"
                               TabHeader="Design">
        <customcontrols:RibbonItem.ItemsSource>
            <customcontrols:RibbonSection SectionHeader="Layout"
                                          SeparatorColor="#ccc" />
        </customcontrols:RibbonItem.ItemsSource>
    </customcontrols:RibbonItem>
    <customcontrols:RibbonItem x:Name="ReviewRibbonItem"
                               Key="review-item"
                               TabHeader="Review">
        <customcontrols:RibbonItem.ItemsSource>
            <customcontrols:RibbonSection SectionHeader="Structure"
                                          SeparatorColor="#ccc" />
        </customcontrols:RibbonItem.ItemsSource>
    </customcontrols:RibbonItem>
</customcontrols:Ribbon.ItemsSource>
```

The problem is that, for some reason, each `RibbonItem` receives all three `RibbonSection`s in its `ItemsSource` (type of `IList<RibbonSection>`) property. If I bind the `ItemsSource` to a `List<RibbonSection>`, it works just fine. Is this a bug in XAML, or is this how it's supposed to behave and I should be doing something differently?

Comment: Impossible to say without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. There's nothing I see in the XAML you show that would explain the behavior you describe (if I understand the description correctly), but whatever "custom control" you're using here might have a bug, or it might be by-design that it operates that way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The amount of code required for this exactly is too much. I'll try to come up with a simpler sample tomorrow. It's definitely not a bug in the control, though. I can see the DP being set incorrectly before the control even initializes or runs my code.

Comment: If it's caused by the XAML compiler, you will be able to reproduce without the custom control component. If you can't reproduce without the custom control component, then that component is the cause, whether by design or a bug.

Comment: It should not be `ItemsSource` It should be `Items` if it is explicitly Assigned. if you want to use `DataBinding` then you need to set `ItemTemplate` and then Bind `ItemsSource`